# If I tell you VS if I would tell you VS if I were to tell you

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, phrase-usage

I would like to know the correct grammar for a specific sentence:

> **If I tell you/If I would tell you/ If I were to tell you**, please promise not to think ill of me.

Which choice would count as the most grammatically correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If I would tell you* implies that the speaker will not tell the addressed person.

*If I were to tell you* draws a hypothetical scenario in the future.

*If I tell you* is the most direct one, that shows a link between the telling, and the thinking ill.